# SetInterval not incrementing from interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, setinterval

```
haha = 0;
function dodat(){
haha++;
code here...
}
setInterval(function(){
dodat();
}, 1500-haha);
```

It is strange, it doesn't seem like time is actually getting added to the setinterval...

Here is my code, SetInterval starts on line `57`, function `dodat()`:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<body onkeypress="pretend();">
<span id="money">25</span>$ - <span id="lives">100</span>/100 lives
<br><br>
<span style="background-color:#2cafe4;cursor:pointer;width:1000px;height:175px;overflow:hidden;position:relative;display:block;" id="track"></span>
<br>
<span id="divthing" style="position:relative;display:block;"></span>


<script>
    money = 25;
    lives = 100;
    mycars = {};
    original = 0;

    function doofus() {
if($("div:first").offset().left > 1000){
        $("div:first").remove();
        lives = lives-1;
        document.getElementById("lives").innerHTML = lives;
}
}
haha = 0;
    function dodat() {
    haha = haha+100;
            var btn = document.createElement("div");
        anyArray = new Array('http://i44.tinypic.com/i4l1r8.png', 'http://i41.tinypic.com/nxs4k8.jpg');
        function randOrd(){
return (Math.round(Math.random())-0.5); }
        anyArray.sort(randOrd);
        btn.innerHTML="<img src='"+anyArray+"' style='height:60px;'>";
        btn.style.position = "absolute";
        btn.style.left = "0px";
        var numba = Math.round(Math.random() * 50);
        btn.class = "haha";
        btn.id = numba;
        mycars[numba] = -50;

        var move = function () {
            mycars[numba] = mycars[numba] + 1.5;
            document.getElementById(numba).style.left = mycars[numba] + "px";
            if(mycars[numba] > 100 && mycars[numba] < 150){
            document.getElementById(numba).style.top = mycars[numba]/0.5-200 + "px";
            }
        };

        setInterval(move, 10);

        document.getElementById("track").appendChild(btn);
    }
    setInterval(function(){
    dodat();
}, 1500-haha);
    setInterval(doofus, 200);

    function dis1() {
        $("#shoot1").css("background-color", "red");
        setTimeout('$("#shoot1").css("background-color", "blue");', '1000');
    compareEl = $("#shoot1");
        // Let's find the closest block!
        var otherEls = $('div'),
            compareTop = compareEl.offset().top,
            compareLeft = compareEl.offset().left,
            winningScore = Infinity,
            score, winner, curEl;

        otherEls.each(function () {
            // Calculate the score of this element
            curEl = $(this);
            score = Math.abs(curEl.offset().left - compareLeft);
            if (score < winningScore) {
                winningScore = score;
                winner = this;
            }
        });
        $("#"+winner.id+"").remove();

        money = money+1;
        document.getElementById("money").innerHTML=""+money+"";
}

    function dis2() {
        $("#shoot2").css("background-color", "red");
        setTimeout('$("#shoot2").css("background-color", "blue");', '1000');
    compareEl2 = $("#shoot2");
        // Let's find the closest block!
        var otherEls2 = $('div'),
            compareTop2 = compareEl2.offset().top,
            compareLeft2 = compareEl2.offset().left,
            winningScore2 = Infinity,
            score2, winner2, curEl2;

        otherEls2.each(function () {
            // Calculate the score of this element
            curEl2 = $(this);
            score2 = Math.abs(curEl2.offset().left - compareLeft2);
            if (score2 < winningScore2) {
                winningScore2 = score2;
                winner2 = this;
            }
        });
        $("#"+winner2.id+"").remove();

        money = money+1;
        document.getElementById("money").innerHTML=""+money+"";
}

    function dis3() {
        $("#shoot3").css("background-color", "red");
        setTimeout('$("#shoot3").css("background-color", "blue");', '1000');
    compareEl3 = $("#shoot3");
        // Let's find the closest block!
        var otherEls3 = $('div'),
            compareTop3 = compareEl3.offset().top,
            compareLeft3 = compareEl3.offset().left,
            winningScore3 = Infinity,
            score3, winner3, curEl3;

        otherEls3.each(function () {
            // Calculate the score of this element
            curEl3 = $(this);
            score3 = Math.abs(curEl3.offset().left - compareLeft3);
            if (score3 < winningScore3) {
                winningScore3 = score3;
                winner3 = this;
            }
        });
        $("#"+winner3.id+"").remove();

        money = money+1;
        document.getElementById("money").innerHTML=""+money+"";
}


    function dis4() {
        $("#shoot4").css("background-color", "red");
        setTimeout('$("#shoot4").css("background-color", "blue");', '1000');
    compareEl4 = $("#shoot4");
        // Let's find the closest block!
        var otherEls4 = $('div'),
            compareTop4 = compareEl4.offset().top,
            compareLeft4 = compareEl4.offset().left,
            winningScore4 = Infinity,
            score4, winner4, curEl4;

        otherEls4.each(function () {
            // Calculate the score of this element
            curEl4 = $(this);
            score4 = Math.abs(curEl4.offset().left - compareLeft4);
            if (score4 < winningScore4) {
                winningScore4 = score4;
                winner4 = this;
            }
        });
        $("#"+winner4.id+"").remove();

        money = money+1;
        document.getElementById("money").innerHTML=""+money+"";
}


    function dis5() {
        $("#shoot5").css("background-color", "red");
        setTimeout('$("#shoot4").css("background-color", "blue");', '1000');
    compareEl5 = $("#shoot5");
        // Let's find the closest block!
        var otherEls5 = $('div'),
            compareTop5 = compareEl5.offset().top,
            compareLeft5 = compareEl5.offset().left,
            winningScore5 = Infinity,
            score5, winner5, curEl5;

        otherEls5.each(function () {
            // Calculate the score of this element
            curEl5 = $(this);
            score5 = Math.abs(curEl5.offset().left - compareLeft5);
            if (score5 < winningScore5) {
                winningScore5 = score5;
                winner5 = this;
            }
        });
        $("#"+winner5.id+"").remove();

        money = money+1;
        document.getElementById("money").innerHTML=""+money+"";
}

function whatareyousingingpatrick(){
if(money >= 15){
money = money-15;
original = original+1;
        setInterval("dis"+original+"();", 2400);
        var btn = document.createElement("shooter");
        btn.style.display = "block";
        btn.id = "shoot"+original+"";
        btn.style.height = "25px";
        btn.style.width = "25px";
        btn.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        btn.innerHTML = "<img src='http://www.bubblews.com/assets/images/news/1317280976_1370202845.png' style='height:100%;width:100%;border-radius:100%;opacity:0.7;'>";
        btn.style.borderRadius= "100%";
        btn.style.boxShadow= "0px 0px 200px 75px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)";
        btn.style.position = "absolute";
        btn.style.left = event.pageX-8;
        btn.style.top = event.pageY-44;
        document.getElementById("track").appendChild(btn);
}
else{
alert("Sorry, this dude costs 15 bucks.");
}
}

function whatareyousingingpatrick2(){
if(money >= 25){
money = money-25;
original = original+1;
        setInterval("dis"+original+"();", 2000);
        var btn = document.createElement("shooter");
        btn.style.display = "block";
        btn.id = "shoot"+original+"";
        btn.style.height = "25px";
        btn.style.width = "25px";
        btn.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        btn.innerHTML = "<img src='http://static3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb62439/xwing-miniatures/images/thumb/1/18/Missile_Icon.png/100px-0,111,0,110-Missile_Icon.png' style='height:100%;width:100%;border-radius:100%;opacity:0.7;'>";
        btn.style.borderRadius= "100%";
        btn.style.boxShadow= "0px 0px 200px 75px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)";
        btn.style.position = "absolute";
        btn.style.left = event.pageX-8;
        btn.style.top = event.pageY-44;
        document.getElementById("track").appendChild(btn);
}
else{
alert("Sorry, this dude costs 25 bucks.");
}
}

function pretend(){
   if (event.keyCode == 13) {
if(money >= 5){
money = money-5;
   $("div").hide();
   alert("You have bought the INSTANT KILL feature. Note that you can purchase this feature an unlimited number of times.");
   }
else
{
alert("Sorry, the cost of the INSTANT KILL feature is 5$");
}
}
if (event.keyCode == 49) {
if(money >= 40){
money = money-40;
   alert("You have bought the FASTER SHOOTING upgrade for your first missile. Note that you can purchase this upgrade an unlimited number of times.");
   setInterval("dis1();", "8000");
   }
   else
{
alert("Sorry, the cost of the FASTER SHOOTING upgrade for this missile is 40$");
}
   }
   if (event.keyCode == 50) {
if(money >= 40){
money = money-40;
   alert("You have bought the FASTER SHOOTING upgrade for your second missile. Note that you can purchase this upgrade an unlimited number of times.");
   setInterval("dis2();", "8000");
   }
   else
{
alert("Sorry, the cost of the FASTER SHOOTING upgrade for this missile is 40$");
}
   }
   if (event.keyCode == 51) {
if(money >= 40){
money = money-40;
   alert("You have bought the FASTER SHOOTING upgrade for your third missile. Note that you can purchase this upgrade an unlimited number of times.");
   setInterval("dis3();", "8000");
   }
   else
{
alert("Sorry, the cost of the FASTER SHOOTING upgrade for this missile is 40$");
}
   }
   if (event.keyCode == 52) {
if(money >= 40){
money = money-40;
   alert("You have bought the FASTER SHOOTING upgrade for your fourth missile. Note that you can purchase this upgrade an unlimited number of times.");
   setInterval("dis4();", "8000");
   }
   else
{
alert("Sorry, the cost of the FASTER SHOOTING upgrade for this missile is 40$");
}
   }
}
</script>
<br><br>
<button onclick='$("#track").on("click", function() { whatareyousingingpatrick(); });'>
Get sniper for 15$
</button>
<br>

<button onclick='$("#track").on("click", function() { whatareyousingingpatrick2(); });'>
Get bomb for 25$
</button>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with `1500-haha` ?

Comment: What are you expecting this to do? The interval of the `setInterval` call will always be `1500` - (1500 - 0). Any processing on the `haha` value after the instantiation is irrelevant.

Comment: About your other post, your quotes were messed up. Don't use variables concatenating function names, use same function passing the variable to the function and then, inside the function, decide what to do.

Comment: what would you suggest instead? @Sergio :) thank you sir

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In

```
setInterval(function(){
   dodat();
}, 1500-haha);
```

The `1500-haha` part is only evaluated once, which means the `-haha` is useless.

If you want the interval to reduce at each call, you might use setTimeout :

```
(function doone(){
    dodat();
    setTimeout(doone, 1500-haha); // a halting condition here would be nice
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

The setInterval will only read that value once. If you want to read it again you have to clear the interval and re-start it.

Something like:

```
var theInterval = setInterval(function () {
    dodat();
}, 1500);
setInterval(doofus, 200);

function reSetIntevar(value) {
    clearInterval(theInterval);
    theInterval = setInterval(function () {
        dodat();
    }, 1500 - value);
    setInterval(doofus, 200);
}
```